# The changes I'm making to my array inside linereader.on are not available outside

Tags: javascript

I'm parsing a data file (which contains json data) line-by-line and creating objects. I then add these objects to an array which I have declared outside. But for some reason, my 'services' array becomes empty again outside the linereader.on function. I'm able to console.log(services) inside the linereader.on and see it printing data as expected. But I have no idea why it becomes empty again outside!

```
const getLineReader = function () {
  return require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('data.txt')
  });
};

const getSystem = function () {
  const lineReader = getLineReader();
  const services = [];

  lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    const serviceJSON = JSON.parse(line);
    const tests = serviceJSON.tests.map(test => {
      return new ServiceTest(
        test.id,
        test.name,
        test.criticality);
    });

    const service = new NewService(new UniqueID(), serviceJSON.name, tests, new Timestamp());

    services.push(service);
    console.log(services); // prints Services { _services: [relevant data here] }

  });

console.log(services); // prints Services { _services: [] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the `readline` [`'close'`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close) event and then print the array. `close` will be called once all lines have been read.

```
lineReader.on('close', function() {
   console.log(services)
});
```

You'll then end up with something like:

```
const getSystem = function () {
    const lineReader = getLineReader();
    const services = [];

    lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
        const serviceJSON = JSON.parse(line);
        const tests = serviceJSON.tests.map(test => {
            return new ServiceTest(
            test.id,
            test.name,
            test.criticality);
        });

        const service = new NewService(new UniqueID(), serviceJSON.name, tests, new Timestamp());

        services.push(service);
        console.log(services); // prints Services { _services: [relevant data here] }
    });

    lineReader.on('close', function() {
        console.log(services)
    });
}
```

In your current code, `console.log(services)` will fire before the line `lineReader.on('line', ...)` code.