# Nodejs readline giving some error

Tags: node.js, readline

I want to read a file line by line and based on the data in each line i have to categorise the data.

```
var rd = readline.createInterface({
 input: fs.createReadStream('/home/user/Desktop/text.txt'),
 output: process.stdout,
 console: false
});
```

When this line is executed the file is read and printed in the terminal.

But when I try to read the file line by line using readline I am getting error.

```
rd.on('line', (input) => {
console.log(input);
});
```

I am getting the following error.

```
`Interface {
 _sawReturnAt: 0,
 isCompletionEnabled: true,
 _sawKeyPress: false,
 _previousKey: 
 { sequence: '\n',
 name: 'enter',
 ctrl: false,
 meta: false,
 shift: false },
 domain: 
 Domain {
 domain: null,
 _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
 _eventsCount: 1,
 _maxListeners: undefined,
 members: [] },
 _events: { line: [ [Function], [Function], [Function] ] },
 _eventsCount: 1,
 _maxListeners: undefined,
 output: 
  WriteStream {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _handle: 
     TTY {
     bytesRead: 0,
    _externalStream: {},
    fd: 9,
    writeQueueSize: 0,
    owner: [Circular],
    onread: [Function: onread] },
 _parent: null,
 _host: null,
 _readableState: 
  ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: [Object],
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    ranOut: false,
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null },
 readable: false,
 domain: null,
 _events: 
  { end: [Object],
    finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
    _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
    resize: [Object] },
 _eventsCount: 4,
 _maxListeners: undefined,
 _writableState: 
  WritableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    decodeStrings: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: false,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    bufferedRequest: null,
    lastBufferedRequest: null,
    pendingcb: 1,
    prefinished: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    bufferedRequestCount: 0,
    corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
 writable: true,
 allowHalfOpen: false,
 destroyed: false,
 _bytesDispatched: 22151,
 _sockname: null,
 _writev: null,
 _pendingData: null,
 _pendingEncoding: '',
 server: null,
 _server: null,
 columns: 80,
 rows: 24,
 _type: 'tty',
 fd: 1,
 _isStdio: true,
 destroySoon: [Function],
 destroy: [Function] },
 input: 
 ReadStream {
 _readableState: 
  ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 65536,
    buffer: [Object],
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: false,
    ended: true,
    endEmitted: true,
    reading: false,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    ranOut: false,
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null },
    readable: false,
     domain: 
    Domain {
    domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    members: [] },
 _events: { end: [Object], data: [Function: onData] },
 _eventsCount: 2,
 _maxListeners: undefined,
 path: '/home/user/Desktop/text.txt',
 fd: null,
 flags: 'r',
 mode: 438,
 start: undefined,
 end: undefined,
 autoClose: true,
 pos: undefined,
 bytesRead: 31,
 destroyed: true,
 closed: true },
 historySize: 30,
 crlfDelay: 100,
_prompt: '> ',
 terminal: true,
 line: '',
 cursor: 0,
 history: [ '1,2,3', '4,8,4,8', '2,2,2,2', '1,2,3,4' ],
 historyIndex: -1,
 prevRows: 0,
 paused: true,
 closed: true }`
```

Please help I am new to this.

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using? `node -v`.

Comment: @dan I am using  v7.7.2

Comment: From the [7.7.2 docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/v7.7.2/api/readline.html#readline_readline_createinterface_options) `console` isn't an option which `createInterface` is expecting, so I think that can be removed. In your particular example, you could also remove `output: process.stdout`, as your logging each line on line. Does removing either of those options from `createInterface` make any difference?

Comment: @dan I have removed those 2 lines and still getting the same error. additionally I am getting a `StringDecoder` object along with previous error.
I am executing this from my terminal

Comment: Other than that, the code you've posted looks absolutely fine. Can you post the rest of the file?

Comment: @dan I am running these code directly from my `node terminal` by coding these lines directly into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147087/discussion-between-dan-and-tony-roczz).

Comment: I've worked out why that object was being logged and updated my answer. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine but you are using the Node.js REPL rather than running the code from a file, which is why you're seeing this behaviour.

The Node.js REPL (what you get when you type `node` in terminal) will store variables. However, when only an identifier is used the value is also returned. What you're seeing isn't an error, but the `rd` object.

The Node.js REPL is good for testing but, unless you have a specific reason for using it, the best thing to do is create an app.js file, add your code to it and then run `node app.js`.

If you do need to write multi-line code using REPL, then be sure to type `.editor` once initialised, so that whitespace, etc. is interpreted correctly.

Also, from the [7.7.2](https://nodejs.org/docs/v7.7.2/api/readline.html#readline_readline_createinterface_options) docs `console` isn't an option which `createInterface` is expecting, so that can be removed. In your particular example, you could also remove `output: process.stdout`, as your logging each line using the `line` event

Comment: After completing process inside the `on` function how can i log the final result? I just create an `array` based on the length of each line. In the end i want to `log` the length of the longest line

Comment: You need to listen to the `close` event to detect when the whole file has been read. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003920/the-changes-im-making-to-my-array-inside-linereader-on-are-not-available-outsid/43004107#43004107